# Too many connections Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I try to run `SELECT` on a table in `MySql` and i get this error:

```
Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.
Too many connections
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Too many connections
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

> [MySqlException (0x80004005): Too many connections]
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +517
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +702
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +245
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +297
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +18
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +403
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +228
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +106
>          MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +1468
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

I run it on iis with .net and C#.
Any idea how i can fix this problem?

## EDIT

I add some code from my server:

This is for example how i make select:

```
MySqlDataReader msdr;

MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

string commandLine = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE active=1";

commandLine = commandLine.Remove(commandLine.Length - 3);
cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.Connection.Open();

msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (msdr.Read())
{
    //Read data
}
msdr.Close();
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

This is how I Delete:

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.Connection.Open();

string commandLine = @"DELETE FROM Table WHERE id=@id;";

cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", slotId);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

This is how I insert:

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.Connection.Open();

string commandLine = @"INSERT INTO Table (id, weekday, start, end) VALUES" +
    "(@ id, @weekday, @start, @end);";

cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ id", item.babysitterid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weekday", item.weekday);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", new TimeSpan(item.starthour, item.startmin, 0));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", new TimeSpan(item.endhour, item.endmin, 0));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
cmd.Connection.Close();
return id;
```

Comment: Do you use the using statement around your connections?

Comment: Probably you should increase max_connections variable in my.ini file in MySql directory. Don't forget turn off MySql (cmd->net stop mysql) before changing variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up the Admin page on your (local) MySql monitor and observe to see if the number of connection grows with time. If this is unexpected behaviour, then you may have unclosed connection objects in your code (see comment from Steve below your question). If this is *not* unexpected i.e. you know that your app will generate and hold a lot of connections, then you may need to change the setting in MySQL

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

by adjusting `max_connections`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

**UPDATE:** if you don't expect and don't need so many open connections, and want to make sure you haven't overlooked any `close()` statements, then good practice is to employ the `using` construction around objects implementing `IDisposable`, such as connections, to make sure that they are closed as soon as possible, allowing the garbage collector to clean up objects no longer in use.

Comment: While increasing the number of allowed connections will sometimes help solving the cause, it does ignore a possible underlying problem. Often the problem isn't just needing more connections, but the lack of connections being properly closed. And depending on the garbage collector and the disposing of the connections will eventually result in the same problem re-emerging again.

Comment: @René: that's exactly my point - the connections need to be closed properly which is what Steve was alluding to. I'll edit my answer to make that a little clearer.

Comment: Ah, right. The `max_connections` seemed so prominent it was easily missed that that was mentioned as well. But your update definitely puts moreemphasis on it. +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think adjusting max connections is the right solution until it's been identified what the problem is. It could add more strain on the server / hide the actual issue.

I would make sure you're closing connections and disposing implicitly by wrapping MySqlConnection and commands in using statements.

Can you post up some code as to how you're communicating with the DB.

Also is this server a local instance?

Comment: Well your code seems to be closing connections fine. You need to see what the connections that are open are doing. It might be a specific query you're forgetting to close or some other system / process that is keeping these open. Are there other applications using this MySQL instance?